# I need to export the security event viewer logs

Tags: powershell

I am having the script to export the security event viewer. In that I need additional information like Caller account name in exporting data. And Date and time is in empty while exporting.

My script

```
 Select-Object EventId, Time, @{ 
   n='AccountName';
   e={ ($_.message -replace '\n', ' ') -replace '.*?account name:\t+([^\s]+).*', '$1' } 
 }, @{
   n='TargetAccount';
   e={ ($_.message -replace '\n', ' ') -replace '.*account name:\t+([^\s]+).*', '$1' } 

 } | Export-Csv 'C:\EventLogs.csv'
```

Event viewer properties screenshot.
[image: Event viewer properties screenshot]

Current output of the script
[image: Current output of the script]

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse a log? Have a look at the `properties` property there is all the info you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
Get-EventLog -LogName Security EventId, Time, @{ 
   n='AccountName';
   e={ ($_.message -replace '\n', ' ') -replace '.*?account name:\t+([^\s]+).*', '$1' } 
 }, @{
   n='TargetAccount';
   e={ ($_.message -replace '\n', ' ') -replace '.*account name:\t+([^\s]+).*', '$1' } 

 } | Export-Csv 'C:\EventLogs.csv' ```
````